# Does Sugar ORM take serialized name for the column name?

Tags: android, database, orm, sugarorm

I want to know if the Sugar ORM take serialized name for the column name in the database.
For eg..

In my pojo,

```
public class myPojo implements Serializable{

@SerializedName("id")
String program_id;

.....
}
```

What does Sugar ORM take as the columnName,
 "id" or "program_id" ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `@SerializedName` just to the mapping between GSON and your objects. For the underlying SQLite database that Sugar manages, you would still have the correspondence:

```
String program_id ----> "PROGRAM_ID"
```

Sources: 
https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/86